# Virtual Box on Windows - screen fonts, icons etc too big

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox

I have been using Virtual Box on Windows for 5 years now with no issues.

I changed my Windows 10 machine few months back. I downloaded the latest version of Virtual Box & installed it on my new machine today. The Font Sizes of the Virtual Box menu are huge, the icons are huge. In many child windows stuff is outside my screen. For e.g. if I click on Help-About - the about window dialog doesn't fit on my monitor - parts of it are outside my laptop screen.

For e.g. my Machine menu extends from top to bottom of my screen (not the Virtual Box Window). It goes right up to the Windows Task Bar at the bottom and even covers the task bar. This is a screenshot with my Virtual Box maximised. I have never had this issue in my earlier machine.

[image]

None of my other applications behave this way on new Windows machine. What is wrong?

Comment: Do you use scaling?  Try turning on advanced scaling in Settings-->Display-->Advanced scaling settings.    It's also reported as a bug here: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16678

Comment: There was a scheduled Windows Update yesterday - after the reboot, the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the answer: From the View menu, select Auto-Resize Guest Display.  It made everything the right size for me.